# Load cshtml view inside html page using AngularJS ui-router

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I've used ui-router to load multiple html pages inside one html page before, now I want to load my cshtml view inside the html page and wouldn't use iframe.
as I couldn't find any proper tutorial, I don't have a clue how it is possible.
any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's wrong with using `ng-include`? Just add an MVC route for your view and use `ng-include="'/my-route/'"`.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this link [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/3d39b4/rendering-a-partial-view-and-json-data-using-ajax-in-Asp-Net/):

> This article explains how to render a partial view and JSON data using AJAX. I have divided this article into three sections to
>   understand both concepts, the first section describes the basic code
>   and structure that is common in both concepts, the second section
>   describes how to render a partial view using AJAX and the last section
>   describes how to render JSON data on a web using AJAX.

This talks about how to get the HTML for a view from an ajax call and then you can do whatever you need to with it.